# Access at 'https://xxx' from origin 'http://localhost:8080/' blocked by CORS policy (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present) error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, axios, cors

I'm currently testing my application locally (backend : springboot, frontend : vue.js with axios) and I get this error with a PUT request (I don't know if the fact that it's PUT is the origin of the error, but this error doesnt show up with other request I tested)

I know this is a frequently reported error here, but I tested every solution I could find on the internet and nothing works

I tested :

adding this on my controller :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
```

adding the same line on the request that generates the error

adding this instead :

```
 @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
```

adding this in my cors configuration bean : (this one actually add new cors errors on the other requests)

```
 @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

adding this bean

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer configurer(){
  return new WebMvcConfigurer(){
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
      registry.addMapping("/*")
          .allowedOrigins("*");
    }
  };
}
```

adding this header in the axios request :

```
   { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*' },
```

I admit I'm a bit lost here. Can anyone help ?

**EDIT : The fact that it's PUT is indeed the source of the error, even tho i don't really know why. But if I transform it into a POST request, it works just fine**

Comment: And what do you get from curl?

Comment: @k-wasilewski no problem with that

Comment: Are you sure you're not intercepting the responses elsewhere in the code? Some jwt for example...

Comment: @k-wasilewski I have a jwt authorization filter, I guess the problem could come from there but I don't really know how

Answer (score 0):

So in your JWT-related classes look for anything that intercepts the response and add this there:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") to the controller didn't work for me either.
What always worked for me was adding a filter that is executed on every request.

```
@Component
public class Filter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


@Override
protected void doFilterInternal( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response, FilterChain filterChain )
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.addHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" );
    response.addHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*" );
    response.addHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*" );
    filterChain.doFilter( request, response );
   }
}
```

Comment: yeah, I have an authorization filter already, I tried adding the headers to it but it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but I also have been solved CORS problem from chrome browser.
You should check axios and vuejs's proxy configuration.
when I configured proxy and it was solved.

or

HA proxy or some load balancers maybe services in front of https:// you need to access.